# Type function's arguments only via Interface TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I type the function's arguments bellow and keep them clean (without Typescript), using Interface?

```
// external file
export interface TSomeFunctionArgs {
   someKey: string
   // also here should be a type for a function
} 

// main file
import { TSomeFunctionArgs } from "pathToFile"

const someFunction = (args: TSomeFunctionArgs) => {
   // ... function's logic
}

someFunction({ someKey: "some string" }, someAnotherFunction)
```

In my example I'm passing two arguments, the first one is an object with the particular key - value pair, and a second one is a function (it could be any function).

How do I describe it in the Interface above?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use generics for, and the code will be something like this:

```js
interface TSomeFunctionArgs {
   someKey: string
} 

const someFunction = <U, T>(args: U, callback: T) => {
   // ... function's logic
}

function someAnotherFunction() {}

// With generics you can give the type of the two parameters when you use it.
someFunction<TSomeFunctionArgs, () => void>({ someKey: "some string" }, someAnotherFunction)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to type the arguments only, not the whole function. So it could be applicable to another functions via export/import

Comment: @Andrew In that case you can use two generics. I edit the code.

Comment: This is not answering the part about `keep it clean`. I need to move `() => void` outside and define them via interface/type

Comment: In that case you can pass an object as argument instead of various arguments, in other way, you can't type the parameter with an interface